# "ellipsisable" navbar centered title

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a top navbar where there is a centered title that should be automatically "ellipsed" when the title is very long or the screen width is narrow. For that I want to use the `text-overflow: ellipsis` property but it seems `text-overflow: ellipsis` requires the element to have a width, which is an issue because I had to make my title element an `inline` element.

Currently my HTML is

```html
<body>
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-container">
        <ul class="pull-left">
          <li>item1</li>
          <li>item2</li>
        </ul>                       

        <h1 class="title">
          <a href="#">My Title</a>
        </h1>     

        <ul class="pull-right">
      <li>item3</li>
      <li>item4</li>
    </ul>
     </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And my CSS:

```css
body {
  width: 100%
}
.navbar {
  position: fixed; 
  text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc; 
  width: inherit;
}               
.navbar-container {
  height: 20px; 
  padding: 20px 18px;
}
ul {
  display:block;
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}                        
li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 18px;
  position: relative;
}             
h1.title {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 17px;
}       
.pull-left {
  float: left;
}
.pull-right {
  float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4CvRH/

Is there any approach (changing the HTML or the CSS) that can achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4CvRH/2/

You can use `inline-block` instead of `inline` if you don't want your `h1` to be a block level element.

```
h1.title {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 17px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```